# REST web services suggestions

Tags: web-services, rest

I want to make a REST services based application and I have no ideas to start with. Do you have any suggestions?
I know what REST services are and how to implement them, but I don't have an idea for what application to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most standard REST example or case study is a content management system. ie a system where the main resources are "documents" (/documents/1 /documents/2 etc). It could also be "posts" for a blog or "tweets" etc.

You can then enhance it with a separate resource for authors, add policies for reading and writing posts, and so on.

The good thing about this model is there's no real business logic or API scraping to implement, and it's easy to test by checking document contents.

Of course, the best projects to use, when you have the luxury of choosing them, are always those you have a passion for developing.